# MSI GTX 1060 Low graphics mode

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

I've followed steps in other posts on how to correctly install and remove nvidia drivers. However, I've encountered issues trying to do this.

I used to have a GTX 1070 (ASUS) which worked okay on the nvidia-378 drivers available through *ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa*. However, after reinstalling these drivers from nothing, they don't work for my 1060. I have done the following:

- ppa-purged the graphics drivers repo using the ppa-purge package and readded it using sudo add-apt-repository
- purged the nvidia drivers and reinstalled using sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-*, sudo apt install nvidia-375
- reinstalled ubuntu desktop using sudo apt install --reinstall

None of these came through with any errors, but despite all this i still boot to a low resolution message saying that my input devices or displays are wrongly configured. I can't boot to desktop at all but I can load the tty.

With help, I've managed to diagnose further. http://termbin.com/pnrf (I'll add the actual output to the question when i reboot my machine) shows the output of running `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50`

Trying to restart LightDM after loading the module does nothing to help the matter. The Xorg.0.log file is here: http://termbin.com/7wse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: @DavidFoerster tried the solutions there: not working

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you try and what happened? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added as much detail as I could at this point

Comment: That's not going to be enough to help you. *How exactly* did you “ppa-purge[…] the graphics drivers repo and readd[…] it”? *How exactly* did you “purge[…] the nvidia drivers and reinstall[…]”? *How exactly* did you “reinstall[…] ubuntu desktop”? What was the result in each of these instances? Were there any warning or error messages?

Comment: @DavidFoerster added my exact methods to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56416/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-jellywx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix with a lot of help from [@DavidFoerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster). Disabled Intel graphics in the BIOS and it seems back to normal. Not sure how long this'll work for or what performance will be like..